# What is the complement of the event?

Tags: probability

If we know that the there is a subgraph $A$ has at least $k$ vertices with a probability at least $p$:
$$P( \mbox{ there is a subgraph } A \mbox{ such that } |A|\ge k)\ge p.$$

What is the complement of the above event? Is that

$$P( \mbox{ any subgraph } A \mbox{ such that } |A|\ge k)< 1- p.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complement of "some thing does that," is "every thing does *not* do that."

In this case: $$\mathsf P(\text{all subgraphs $A$ will satisfy $\lvert A\rvert < k$})~=~1-p$$

---

Alternatively you could use "no thing does that".

$$\mathsf P(\text{no subgraph $A$ will satisfy $\lvert A\rvert \geq k$})~=~1-p$$

Comment: How about "there is a"?

Comment: "there is a", and "some " are synonymous.  They are existential claims.